# KIF and Quick/Nimble

Tags: ios, unit-testing, integration-testing, kif

I'm trying to get [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF) and [Quick/Nimble](https://github.com/Quick/Quick) for iOS playing together nicely, so I can use QuickSpecs for my KIF tests.

My test currently looks like this:

```
class HomeSceenSpec: QuickSpec {

    override func spec() {
        describe("Home screen") {
            it("should have a failing test") {
                let tester = self.tester()
                tester.waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel("Blah")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The text 'Blah' doesn't exist and the test *should* fail. `failWithException:stopTest:` is being called but it isn't raising an exception or causing the QuickSpec test to fail.

How do I integrate these two technologies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there may be an issue with `failWithException:stopTest:` calling `recordFailureWithDescription:inFile:atLine:expected:`. (There's a good deal of swizzling going on with that method).

The solution I came to was to create a category/extension on QuickSpec:

```
import Quick
import Nimble
import KIF

extension QuickSpec {

    func tester(_ file : String = __FILE__, _ line : Int = __LINE__) -> KIFUITestActor {
        return KIFUITestActor(inFile: file, atLine: line, delegate: self)
    }

    func system(_ file : String = __FILE__, _ line : Int = __LINE__) -> KIFSystemTestActor {
        return KIFSystemTestActor(inFile: file, atLine: line, delegate: self)
    }

    override public func failWithException(exception: NSException!, stopTest stop: Bool) {
        if let userInfo = exception.userInfo {
            fail(exception.description,
                file: userInfo["SenTestFilenameKey"] as String,
                line: userInfo["SenTestLineNumberKey"] as UInt)
        } else {
            fail(exception.description)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use `XCTFail()` instead of `fail()` if you're not using Nimble. The arguments are the same for both functions. (`fail` ultimately calls `XCTFail` under the hood).

Answer (score 2):

We just released `KIF-Quick` cocoapod that should help, see:

http://cocoapods.org/pods/KIF-Quick

Here an example of spec:

```
import Quick
import KIF_Quick

class LoginSpec: KIFSpec {
    override func spec() {
        describe("successful login") {
            context("home view") {
                beforeEach() {
                    tester().navigateToLoginPage()
                }

                it("should open Welcome page") {
                    viewTester().usingLabel("Login User Name").enterText("user@example.com")
                    viewTester().usingLabel("Login Password").enterText("thisismypassword")
                    viewTester().usingLabel("Log In").tap()
                    viewTester().usingLabel("Welcome").waitForView()
                }

                afterEach() {
                    tester().returnToLoggedOutHomeScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```